# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 When i change no in my predermined set it give error

Tags: java

Hey guys can u please help my problem. i got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:43)

The problem is when i assign number in my set some number program can run properly and some no will give above error.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        //System.out.println("Enter your number?");

        //Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 

        //declare array
        String set[] = new String[3];


        set[0] = "2,9"; // change the number in this set some number give error while some do not have error
        set[1] = "3,7"; 
        set[2] = "8,2";


        //store number in array set
//      for(int i=0;i < 3;i++){
//          System.out.println("Input for " + i);
//          set[i] = scn.nextLine();
//          
//      }

        //determine whether it is transitive or not
        int a = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int b = 0 ;

        for(int i =0 ;i<3 || d == -1 ;i++)
        {

            for(int j= 0 ;j<3 || d == -1 ;j++)
            {
                a= 0 ;

                if (i == j)
                    a = 2 ;

                else if(set[i].charAt(2) == set[j].charAt(0)) //this line that returned error
                    for(int k =0 ;k<3 ;k++)
                    {
                        if (set[k].charAt(0)==set[i].charAt(0) && set[k].charAt(2)==set[j].charAt(2))
                        {
                            a= 1;
                            b++ ;
                        }

                    }
                else
                    a = 2 ;

                if( a== 0)
                    d= -1 ;


            }


        }

        if(b == 0 || d == -1)
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        else
            System.out.println("Valid");

            System.out.println("***********************************************************");
            //reflexive
            //cnt used to determine whether all the no have their reflexive
            //variable reflex is used to store value of set so that we can compare with set
            //to determine whether the no in set got reflexive or not
            //variable g is used to determine whether the no have reflexive or not

            int cnt = 0 ;
            int g = 0 ;
            char reflex[] = new char[3*2];
            int t = 0 ;

            //insert set value to reflex variable
            for(int m= 0; m<3; m++)
            {
                 reflex[t] = set[m].charAt(0);
                t++ ;
                 reflex[t] = set[m].charAt(2);
                t++ ;
                }

            //determine whether all of no have reflexive or not
            for(int n=0 ; n<6 ;n++){
                g= 0 ;
                for(int o=0 ; o<3 ;o++)
                    if(set[o].charAt(o) == reflex[n] && set[o].charAt(2) == reflex[n])
                        g= 1 ;
                if(g == 1)
                    cnt++ ;

            }

            if(cnt == 6)
                System.out.println("Valid Bro");
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid");



            System.out.println("***********************************************************");
            //symmetry
            int u = 0 ;
            int count = 0 ;

            for(int r= 0 ;r<3 ;r++)
            {
                u = 0;
                for(int s =0 ;s<3 ;s++)
                {
                    if(set[s].charAt(0)== set[r].charAt(2) && set[s].charAt(2)== set[r].charAt(0))
                        u= 1;
                }
                if(u==1)
                    count++ ;
            }

            if(count == 3)
                System.out.println("Valid Bro");
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid");

        }   

    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the cause is that your J loop can run even when J get's incremented above 2, which means later in the code it tries to access set[3], but the set is only 3 long, so, 0, 1 and 2. You will need to change some of your logic to accommodate that. Same with the i loop.

Comment: Put a break-point and follow the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen in your code, this seems to be the offending line

```
 for(int i =0 ;i<3 || d == -1 ;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Outer Loop "+i);


                for(int j= 0 ;j<3 || d == -1 ;j++)
                {
```

I really am not sure why you are checking if j<3||d==-1  because what is happening is when i=2,j-2. the value of d is getting set to -1, and this means the inner loop is taking an extra iteration, which results in the exception. Unless you really need to check d==-1 remove the part, and it works like a charm, so should be

```
for(int i =0 ;i<3  ;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Outer Loop "+i);


                    for(int j= 0 ;j<3  ;j++)
                    {
```